# Schema.org - JSON-LD For External Sites?

Tags: json, web, schema, json-ld

I have some Schema.org JSON-LD like:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name": "Name",
  "alternateName": "Alt Name",
  "url": "http://Website.com"
}
 </script>
```

And i have a website with pages where i list other peoples websites with a URL and a bit of info text.

Could i add the Schema.org JSON-LD data for all the external websites? like:

```
"name": "External Website 001",
```

Or does does it have to be used only once for my own website details on the main page etc?

Comment: Could you include a JSON-LD example that shows your idea?

Comment: Basically i would just copy and paste that into every page with a url on it changing the urls and site name etc, rather than having a php script to dynamically write it. So the above is the example but i just want to know if it is a good idea or not or if it could be a negative thing in terms of SEO. I know that some people use fake richsnippets etc to make fake stars appear in google etc and i only found JSON-LD today and know little about it in regards to how it effects SEO. So basically is it good to use lots of it? should i just use it on one page? or would using it lots be bad for SEO?

Comment: Note that the SEO perspective (= if something is good/bad in the eyes of search engines) is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Such questions can be asked on [webmasters.se]. -- I tried to answer your question from the perspective of Schema.org.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say something about another website, it’s perfectly fine to use the `WebSite` type. Schema.org types are not required to be exclusively about your own things.

Let’s say you are reviewing the other website. Then you could use something like:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Review",
  "url": "/reviews/acme-website",
  "itemReviewed": 
  {
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "name": "ACME",
    "url": "http://acme.example.com/"
  }
}
</script>
```

If it’s not a review, but an article about the site, you could use `Article` (instead of `Review`) and its [`about`](http://schema.org/about) property (instead of `itemReviewed`).

Comment: the way you write the first url looks like a review page and you would add this to an index page filled with review pages. Is it possible to add it directly to the code of the actual review page? I guess what i am doing isn't really a review but more of an overview of each site i list like a url directory. For the first url could i just have the current pages url, or does it have to be linked to another page?

Comment: @zeddex: My JSON-LD snippet can be included in the page itself (it’s, in fact, the preferred place for it). It makes sense to provide the `url` even if the `script` element is on the page `/reviews/acme-website`. Neither Schema.org nor JSON-LD assume that a thing without `url` has the URL of the current page. -- Or in other words: `url` should always be the canonical URL of the thing in question, no matter on which page the markup is included.

Comment: so the first url tag could be: http://website.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2 for example? And if the review page just had a websites title, description and a URL link on it, then the websites title on the page was the same as the name tag and the URL on the page was the same as the second url tag in the JSON-LD this would be good for SEO? or would using Article be more appropriate?

Comment: @zeddex: (Asking for SEO is not in scope here.) Sorry, I don’t understand this; it’s hard to discuss something like this in the comments. Unless this is related to your initial question, you might want to ask a new question. If it’s related to your initial question, you could edit your question and provide details (but that’s only appropriate if you don’t change your question).